# Session state returning CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED when no Facebook app is installed in device

Tags: android, facebook

I don't have Facebook app installed in device. When I try to login via fb through my app I am getting session state as CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED. And login doesn't happen.

But if I have fb app installed in my device, everything works fine. I checked key hashes too. Its the same. If through fb app its working then why its not opening browser for fb login and complete process?

I am not able to figure out where is the issue. Could anyone give me some clue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code on how you're creating and opening the session. Also, if the state is going to CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED, there should be an exception that you can log from the StatusCallback.

Answer (score 0):

By my knowledge, To login Facebook by third party apps, you have to installed apps facebook.
So my recommendation, you should use code test that device have facebook apps or not.if not then, you should redirect user to install Facebook in Google play.

or Checked [Developer Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android)

Comment: In developer page, its mentioned clearly:
If the user doesn't have the Facebook for Android app installed on their device, they will be shown a web login dialog inside a WebView.
In my case this web view is not coming.

Comment: if you want know the problem, you should look at logcat.